# Get displaytag to use an action URL for page switching

Tags: portlet, displaytag, jsr286

I'm trying to use external paging in a JSR-286 portlet with DisplayTag 1.2.

I would like DisplayTag to generate the paging links from a parameterized Action URL that i have defined, but i can't seem to make that work.

Here is the code in my JSP:

```jsp
<portlet:actionURL var=actionUrl >
<portlet:param name="someParam" value="someValue" >
</portlet:actionURL >

<display-el:table id="personsTable"
                  name="${portletSessionScope.persons}"
                  requestURI="${actionUrl}"
                  partialList="true"
                  size="${portletSessionScope.total}"
                  pagesize="${portletSessionScope.pageSize}" >

<display-el:column property="firstName"/ >


</display-el:table >
```

With the above code, it looks like Display-tag ignores the provided ${actionUrl} and generates a default Render URL. The generated links work fine (i can move through pages), but since my portlet requires an Action request to fetch other pages of data, the list in the session is never updated and the table always contains the same data, regardless of which page i select.

Is there a way i might make that work? Does DisplayTag support what i'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your code is not being displayed. Please correct this on your question

Comment: please provide me some help regarding my problem.......

Comment: anyone have solution of this problem I am waiting for responses.....

Answer (score 0):

Create a form in your JSP and pass the form name to the `displaytag:table` as form attribute value. This will invoke the action URL that you have specified.